# iOS using vImage - Accelerate to convert QCAR YUV to RGB

Tags: ios, uiimage, vuforia, accelerate-framework, vimage

I'm trying to test the performance of converting YUV images produced by Vuforia and converting them to `UIImage` using the iOS Accelerate Framework's vImage calls. In the current state of the code I'm just trying to get it to work. Right now converting yields a dark striped image. Are there any published details about how Vuforia has laid out the YUV format in their implementation? My initial assumption was that they used the bi-planar 420p format iOS devices use. Relevant test code follows.

```
UIImage *imageWithQCARCameraImage(const QCAR::Image *cameraImage)
{
    UIImage *image = nil;

    if (cameraImage) {
        QCAR::PIXEL_FORMAT pixelFormat = cameraImage->getFormat();

        CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = NULL;
        switch (pixelFormat) {
            case QCAR::YUV:
            case QCAR::RGB888:
                colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
                break;
            case QCAR::GRAYSCALE:
                colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
                break;
            case QCAR::RGB565:
            case QCAR::RGBA8888:
            case QCAR::INDEXED:
                std::cerr << "Image format conversion not implemented." << std::endl;
                break;
            case QCAR::UNKNOWN_FORMAT:
                std::cerr << "Image format unknown." << std::endl;
                break;
        }

        int bitsPerComponent = 8;
        int width = cameraImage->getWidth();
        int height = cameraImage->getHeight();
        const void *baseAddress = cameraImage->getPixels();
        size_t totalBytes = QCAR::getBufferSize(width, height, pixelFormat);

        CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault | kCGImageAlphaNone;
        CGColorRenderingIntent renderingIntent = kCGRenderingIntentDefault;
        CGImageRef imageRef = NULL;

        if (pixelFormat == QCAR::YUV) {
            int bytesPerPixel = 4;
            uint8_t *sourceDataAddress = (uint8_t *)baseAddress;

            static vImage_Buffer srcYp = {
                .width = static_cast<vImagePixelCount>(width),
                .height = static_cast<vImagePixelCount>(height),
                .data = const_cast<void *>(baseAddress)
            };

            size_t lumaBytes = width * height;
            size_t chromianceBytes = totalBytes - lumaBytes;
            static vImage_Buffer srcCb = {
                .data = static_cast<void *>(sourceDataAddress + lumaBytes)
            };

            static vImage_Buffer srcCr = {
                .data = static_cast<void *>(sourceDataAddress + lumaBytes + (chromianceBytes / 2))
            };

            static vImage_Buffer dest = {
                .width = static_cast<vImagePixelCount>(width),
                .height = static_cast<vImagePixelCount>(height),
                .data = imageData
            };

            //uint8_t permuteMap[] = { 1, 2, 3, 0 };
            vImage_YpCbCrPixelRange pixelRange = (vImage_YpCbCrPixelRange){ 0, 128, 255, 255, 255, 1, 255, 0 };
            vImage_YpCbCrToARGB info;

            vImage_Error error;

            error = vImageConvert_YpCbCrToARGB_GenerateConversion(kvImage_YpCbCrToARGBMatrix_ITU_R_601_4,
                                                                  &pixelRange,
                                                                  &info,
                                                                  kvImage420Yp8_Cb8_Cr8,
                                                                  kvImageARGB8888,
                                                                  kvImagePrintDiagnosticsToConsole);


            error = vImageConvert_420Yp8_Cb8_Cr8ToARGB8888(&srcYp,
                                                           &srcCb,
                                                           &srcCr,
                                                           &dest,
                                                           &info,
                                                           NULL,
                                                           1,
                                                           kvImageNoFlags);

            vImage_CGImageFormat format =
            {
                .bitsPerComponent = static_cast<uint32_t>(bitsPerComponent),
                .bitsPerPixel = static_cast<uint32_t>(3 * bitsPerComponent),
                .colorSpace = colorSpace,
                .bitmapInfo = bitmapInfo,
                .version = 0,
                .decode = NULL,
                .renderingIntent = renderingIntent
            };

            imageRef = vImageCreateCGImageFromBuffer(&dest,
                                                     &format,
                                                     NULL,
                                                     NULL,
                                                     kvImageNoFlags,
                                                     &error);
            if (error) {
                std::cerr << "Err." << std::endl;
            }
        } else {
            int bitsPerPixel = QCAR::getBitsPerPixel(pixelFormat);
            int bytesPerRow = cameraImage->getStride();
            CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL,
                                                                      baseAddress,
                                                                      totalBytes,
                                                                      NULL);

           imageRef = CGImageCreate(width,
                                    height,
                                    bitsPerComponent,
                                    bitsPerPixel,
                                    bytesPerRow,
                                    colorSpace,
                                    bitmapInfo,
                                    provider,
                                    NULL,
                                    false,
                                    renderingIntent);
            CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
        }

        if (imageRef != NULL) {
            image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
            CGImageRelease(imageRef);
        }

        if (colorSpace != NULL) {
            CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
        }

    }

    return image;
}
```

Comment: Any published details from Qualcomm has so far been nothing but useless. But in their forums, the moderators "try" to answer questions. If it's a good question there's only two ways they will respond, "Refer to documentation" or an actual answer. Hope you get your answer though, sounds interesting.

Comment: I'll ask on the forum too, although their forum isn't great. What I have learned about YUV tells me that their API doesn't provide enough detail for you to do anything but guess since there are a myriad of potential formats.

Comment: Very very true! Qualcomm needs to step it up.

Comment: You need to fill out all four fields of the vImage_Buffer struct every time.

Comment: @IanOllmann that is why I stated just for testing. If however, you're going to make such a claim for functionality it would be helpful if you would provide a citation, if you're talking about performance then that is why I stated it was for testing. Make it work, make it right, make it fast. In that order.

Comment: I am my own citation on this. Burning bushes will be supplied as required.

Comment: One burning bush, please.

Comment: Ian is the canonical authority on the subject of all things vImage.  When he demands sacrifice, you find a goat.

Comment: However, doesn't answer the basic question to this which is... What is the format of a Vuforia YUV frame?

Answer (score 4):

```
void *baseAddress = buffer;
size_t totalBytes = width * height * 3 / 2;

uint8_t *sourceDataAddress = (uint8_t *)baseAddress;

vImage_Buffer srcYp = {
    .width = static_cast<vImagePixelCount>(width),
    .height = static_cast<vImagePixelCount>(height),
    .rowBytes = static_cast<size_t>(width),
    .data = const_cast<void *>(baseAddress),
};

size_t lumaBytes = width * height;
size_t chromianceBytes = totalBytes - lumaBytes;
vImage_Buffer srcCb = {
    .width = static_cast<vImagePixelCount>(width) / 2,
    .height = static_cast<vImagePixelCount>(height) / 2,
    .rowBytes = static_cast<size_t>(width) / 2,
    .data = static_cast<void *>(sourceDataAddress + lumaBytes),
};

vImage_Buffer srcCr = {
    .width = static_cast<vImagePixelCount>(width) / 2,
    .height = static_cast<vImagePixelCount>(height) / 2,
    .rowBytes = static_cast<size_t>(width) / 2,
    .data = static_cast<void *>(sourceDataAddress + lumaBytes + (chromianceBytes / 2)),
};

vImage_Buffer dest;
dest.data = NULL;
vImage_Error error = kvImageNoError;
error = vImageBuffer_Init(&dest, height, width, 32, kvImageNoFlags);
// vImage_YpCbCrPixelRange pixelRange = (vImage_YpCbCrPixelRange){ 0, 128, 255, 255, 255, 1, 255, 0 };
vImage_YpCbCrPixelRange pixelRange = { 16, 128, 235, 240, 255, 0, 255, 0 };
vImage_YpCbCrToARGB info;
error = kvImageNoError;
error = vImageConvert_YpCbCrToARGB_GenerateConversion(kvImage_YpCbCrToARGBMatrix_ITU_R_601_4,
                                                      &pixelRange,
                                                      &info,
                                                      kvImage420Yp8_Cb8_Cr8,
                                                      kvImageARGB8888,
                                                      kvImagePrintDiagnosticsToConsole);
error = kvImageNoError;
uint8_t permuteMap[4] = {3, 2, 1, 0}; // BGRA - iOS only support BGRA
error = vImageConvert_420Yp8_Cb8_Cr8ToARGB8888(&srcYp,
                                               &srcCb,
                                               &srcCr,
                                               &dest,
                                               &info,
                                               permuteMap, // for iOS must be no NULL, mac can be NULL iOS only support BGRA
                                               255,
                                               kvImageNoFlags);
```

Comment: [edit] your answer and add explanation how/why this code solves the issue (above code, not somewhere in comments).

Comment: essentially, the op's mistake was not to divide by 2 the width and height in srcCb and srcCr. "The two chroma planes (blue and red projections) are sub-sampled in both the horizontal and vertical dimensions by a factor of 2". See https://wiki.videolan.org/YUV